# How can I play a specific channel in a CoreMidi track?

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio, midi, coremidi

I'm able to mute/unmute midi audio tracks with ease using MusicPlayer's MusicTrackSetProperty(t, kSequenceTrackProperty_MuteStatus...) method. But, I haven't wrapped my wits around how to enable/disable specific midi channels within the track. Is there a mute/unmute or disable/enable property for channels within a track?

Would something like this done on the track level, or should I be manipulating the midi synth audio unit in some fashion?

Creating an endpoint does me no good, because I only get a copy of events sent to the synth, not a callback that I can see for filtering what's going to the synth. So, I'm thinking there's probably something that can be tweaked in the audio unit graph, but what exactly?

Someone might suggest opening the midi file with the kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks flag and then simply unmute the track corresponding to the channel and mute the rest. I tried doing that, but I actually get /less/ tracks when opening the midi file that way then without the kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks flag. Odd. Maybe I should understand why that's the case, huh? Here's what I have for a midi file: 16 tracks each containing 6 channels of midi. Without the kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks, I get 16 tracks, with the kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks flag, 12. Shouldn't it be 16*6 tracks?

Thank your for your help. Best to you. /Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. To my knowledge, kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks will coalesce common channels.  So if given two tracks containing notes from three channels each, let's say track1 has notes on channels 1,2,and 3.  And track2 has notes on channels 3,4,and 5. Then using the kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks flag will coalesce the notes using channel 3 from track1 and track2 to a new track. The total number of tracks would be 5 using that method.  That's probably the way to go unless you can prove otherwise. Otherwise, if you really need to pick things apart the endpoint is a valid approach. You just need to send the midi events manually instead of making a connection (pointing a track to a synth).  In your callback you are supposed to parse the midi and call  MusicDeviceMIDIEvent to trigger the synth directly. You could do your filtering there.

Comment: I'll have to go the filtering route, because we send each channel to a device along with hearing the results, the device is expecting 6 channels per track. Good to know about the coalescing though, I always wondered about what was going on there.